# How to make face between two layers of irregular pipe

Tags: faces

How to make face between two layers of irregular pipe. I select edges  of both layers and try to make face but I get the face which closes  pipe instead of connecting these two layers to one wall. 
[image: Selected two edges]

[image: big face closing the pipe]

Comment: with the selection in your first image press `W` then "*Bridge Edge Loops*"

Answer (score 2):

You can use the bridge edge loops option in order to combine the loops.

You can find some additional information on the blender Wiki. In order to get a seamless connection between the two meshes both need to have the same number of vertices otherwise some will have multiple connecting edges.

[Link](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/edges.html)